# Remove a line selectively between 2 particular cells (horizontally and vertically)

Tags: tables, line, border

Is there a simple way to remove a line selectively between 2 particular cells. Let's say for example the vertical line between cell4 and cell5 and the horizontal line between cell6 and cell9?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
  \begin{center}
    \label{tab:table1}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|} % <-- Alignments: 1st column left, 2nd middle and 3rd right, with vertical lines in between
 \hline
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 \hline
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
 \hline
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
 \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]
What I want to do is remove the lines pointed in red.

[image]

Comment: The instruction `\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}` is in open and irreconcilable conflict with the adjacent comment, viz., "Alignments: 1st column left, 2nd middle and 3rd right, with vertical lines in between". Did you mean to (a) write `\begin{tabular}{|l|c|r|}` or (b) comment "all three columns left-aligned"? A separate issue: Isn't the line between "cell6" and "cell9" *horizontal* rather than vertical? Please fix.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Mico. line between "cell6" and "cell9" is indeed horizontal. I corrected the question accordingly

Comment: @Mico. I also made a sketch to make the question clearer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easier to show than explain.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
  \begin{center}
    \label{tab:table1}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|} % <-- Alignments: 1st column left, 2nd middle and 3rd right, with vertical lines in between
 \hline
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 \hline
 \multicolumn{1}{|l}{cell4} & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
 \cline{1-2}
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
 \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you have a key `hvlines` to draw all the verticals and horizontal rules.

However, there is a command `\Block` and the rules are not drawn in those blocks. In your example, I have used two commands `\Block`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]

\centering

\begin{NiceTabular}{lll}[hvlines] 
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 \Block{1-2}{} cell4 & cell5 & \Block{2-1}{} cell6 \\ 
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]